# Cloud Run - Python request into service's own url throws [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have an app deployed on Cloud Run. For some purposes, I want to send a post request to my own app's endpoint.

Assume my app's url: https://test.app/api

```
import requests

requests.post(
   url="https://test.app/api"
)
```

So when I send that request, it throws the error below.

```
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='https', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //test.app/api (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x3ede300bdb80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))"))
```

Is there a way to make a request to my own app inside the app that deployed on Cloud Run?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked this [documentation](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution) regarding `resolv.conf` file configuration or firewall restrictions?

Comment: @RobertG thank you. Yes I've checked it, I guess its something related to Vpc configuration. However, my problem was actually about background tasks so thats why I needed this kind of method. I have solved it by changing my system design.

Comment: please post this as an answer so that other community members with similar questions will find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I could not solve the problem and I decided to change my system design. The problem was related to background tasks (like running multiple background task at the same time) actually and I needed to use app's own api url in a background task.

In my case, I am using Google Scheduler to manage background tasks.

I think this problem can be solved by configuring VPC networks.